# devise sign_in after sign_out error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a little problem with devise. After signing out, when i fill up  "signing in" form first time it writes a validation error

> You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.

but when i am submitting form second time i don't have any errors. And signs in successfully.

I do sign out using link

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

also, after signing up, it redirects me on signing in form and writes validation error:

> You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.

but entering the same again it works fine

what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.

This error message is cause from `authenticate_user!` in controller.

I think your redirection have sent you to some where that have the method

```
before_filter: authenticate_user!
```

For the after you `sign_out` by default devise will redirect you to ***root_path***. [See this link for detail for redirection after sign out.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L217-219)

And for the after `sign_up` devise will redirection you to ***root_path*** or the path that you want to go. [See this link for after signup redirection.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L84-94)

I hope this might help where you miss in your code.

Try to check your root in route file.

Comment: In this case I guess your root is set to some controller that have authenticate_user!