# Rails Devise: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing" instead of "You will receive an email with instructions.."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, confirmation-email, email-confirmation

I have setup Devise on Rails 4.2.0 and everything seems to be working, I used the guide at:

http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

My devise modules are:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
```

The only problem is that if I try to create a new account by going to the signup page, then after entering my email and new password (twice), I am taken back to the signin page and see the 'unauthenticated' message:

```
 You need to sign in or sign up before continuing
```

When instead I should get the 'send_instructions' message:

```
 You will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes.
```

I have a before_filter in my ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show]
```

Though I confess that I don't understand why this doesn't give me authenticate errors on the signin page or the 'forgot password' page.  Either way I tried adding :new_user_session to the :except, but that didn't help.

How can I get the right flash notice for when someone is signing up?

I have not overridden any of the devise code (other than what the sourcey doc suggests), my DeviseHelper only has a method for printing out the flash messages:

```
def devise_error_messages!
    return '' if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    messages.html_safe
end
```

---

EDIT:

My initial search of SO didn't help (too many similar questions that weren't relevant) but now I've found this:

[devise sign_in after sign_out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152276/devise-sign-in-after-sign-out-error)

So I believe the problem is that Devise is trying to take me to my root_path after I do the sign_up action.  I don't know why it would do that for a :confirmable setup, it seems it should take me back to the sign_in page.

I tried to override this by overriding 'after_sign_up_path_for' in a cutom registrations controller using:

[Override devise registrations controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546289/override-devise-registrations-controller)

Perhaps I did it wrong, but that didn't seem to help.

So now the question is, how do I get Devise to go back to the sign_in page after someone does a sign_up, and why isn't this the default action for a confirmable setup?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately since it took so long, I ended up putting this project on the back shelf and haven't had a chance to context switch back to it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned overriding `after_sign_up_path_for` in a custom registrations controller, but following the the direction in [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out), you might want to try placing that in your application_controller.rb.